# Sqrt returns complex values

Tags: complex

I am trying to find sine from a cosine relation using the following commands:

```
CosEta[x_,y_] := 1/2 Cosh[Log[3]/2] (-Sqrt[y^2 + (x - Sech[Log[3]/2])^2] + Sqrt[y^2 + (x + Sech[Log[3]/2])^2]);    

sinsquare[x_,y_] := 1 - (CosEta[x,y])^2;    

SinEta[x_,y_] := Sqrt[sinsquare[x,y]];
```

At some point, i.e.     `x-> 1.1, y-> -0.000000001`    ,
`CosEta[x,y]`     becomes    `-4.44089 * 10^-16`, and as a consequence,     `SinEta`     returns complex number as     `0. + 2.10734 * 10^-8 I`    . What can be done to get rid of this complex number return?

I have to implement this commands in my full code which includes multiple 1st and 2nd derivatives of `SinEta` and `CosEta` for which I can not use `Re[]` in defining the `SinEta` since `Re'` and `Re''` shows up in the final outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is better to pass exact numbers to eliminate the chance of round off errors and at the *very* end apply `N` to the result. This way any accumulated round off are eliminated.

Added FullSimplify and now the complex value is gone

```
CosEta[x_, y_] := 
  1/2   Cosh[
    Log[3]/2]   (-Sqrt[y^2 + (x - Sech[Log[3]/2])^2] + 
     Sqrt[y^2 + (x + Sech[Log[3]/2])^2]);
sinsquare[x_, y_] := (1 - (CosEta[x, y])^2)
SinEta[x_, y_] := FullSimplify[Sqrt[sinsquare[x, y]]]
{CosEta[x, y], sinsquare[x, y], SinEta[x, y]} /. {x -> 1.1, 
   y -> -0.000000001} // Chop
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To elaborate, the problem was this

```
CosEta[x_,y_]:=FullSimplify[1/2  Cosh[Log[3]/2]  (-Sqrt[y^2+(x-Sech[Log[3]/2])^2]+Sqrt[y^2+(x+Sech[Log[3]/2])^2])];
sinsquare[x_,y_]:=(1-(CosEta[x,y])^2)
SinEta[x_,y_]:=Sqrt[sinsquare[x,y]]
```

And now

```
SinEta[x, y]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Plugging  `{x -> 1.1, y -> -0.000000001}` into the above gives complex

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But if we first simplify the expression

```
 SinEta[x, y] // FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And if we now plug the  same x and y values it now gives small real value and no complex.

```
 (SinEta[x, y] // FullSimplify) /. {x -> 1.1, y -> -0.000000001}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: In my case it is not working though. I have not set numerical values to x and y rather I have replaced x and y with the values like:
    {CosEta[x, y], sinsquare[x, y], SinEta[x, y]} /. {x -> 1.1, 
  y -> -0.000000001}
The same problem persists!!

Comment: @PKD see update above and screen shot. Make sure you are using the code I have. V 14  what is the problem you are seeing if you are using same code? What version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: No. I am copy-pasting your code and not getting the Output you showed. No idea why its not working in my case. I am using V13.3

Comment: @PKD I just noticed you are not calling it the same way I show. What happens if you do this: ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4plY.png)  exactly as it shows in the screen shot?  You should now not get any complex number.

Comment: As I said, I am not setting the numbers to x and y. If I do, yes, I get the correct output as you showed. But I can not define x and y in my code and have to retain them as free variables. Why it is causing a problem if replace x and y with the numbers?

Comment: @PKD Ok, I found another way around it.  Try the new version now and see. No more complex. You have small number left but it is real. It seem a round off issue when putting the numbers in the original expression. After simplifying, complex do not show up.  You can change Chop delta to eliminate this small real value if needed

Comment: It looks good but since I have to do multiple derivatives of SinEta, i.e. D[SinETa[x,y], y], I am not sure if the derivatives can bypass the round off errors or not. Let me try.

Comment: `SinEta[1.1, 1.*^-9]` gives an imaginary result, but it you define it with `=` instead of `:=`, it works in the same way as replacement rules.

Comment: @PKD This gives an imaginary result: `SinEta[x, y] /. {x -> 4.*^9, y -> 1.}`.

Answer (score 1):

The OP's code for `CosEta` suffers from subtractive/catastrophic cancellation when `y` is a small floating point number. This may be remedied by rationalization. Simplification will change the round-off error, change the edge cases, but is not designed to eliminate the problem.

Here is a version of `CosEta`, obtained by rationalizing the OP's code for it.

```
(* Num. stable *)
CosEta[x_, y_] := (2 x)/(
  Sqrt[y^2 + (x - Sech[Log[3]/2])^2] + 
   Sqrt[y^2 + (x + Sech[Log[3]/2])^2]);

sinsquare[x_, y_] := (1 - CosEta[x, y]^2)(*(1+CosEta[x,y])*);

SinEta[x_, y_] := Sqrt[sinsquare[x, y]];
```

OP's example:

```
SinEta[x, y] /. {x -> 1.1, y -> -0.000000001}

(* 0. *)

SinEta[1.1, -0.000000001]

(* 0. *)
```

More edge cases. The above code:

```
Table[
   SeedRandom[n, Method -> "MersenneTwister"];(* for reproducibility *)
   With[{x = RandomReal[{-6, 20}]}, 
    SinEta[x, x*$MachineEpsilon*RandomReal[2^28]]],
   {n, 200}] // Im // Counts

(* <|0 -> 200|> *)
```

With OP's code for `CosEta`:

```
Table[
   SeedRandom[n, Method -> "MersenneTwister"];(* for reproducibility *)
   With[{x = 10^RandomReal[{-6, 20}]}, 
    SinEta[x, x*$MachineEpsilon*RandomReal[2^24]]],
   {n, 200}] // Im // Counts // KeySort
(*
<|0 -> 140, 2.10734*10^-8 -> 2, 3.65002*10^-8 -> 4, 
 1.47514*10^-7 -> 2, 4.67906*10^-7 -> 5, 1.83557*10^-6 -> 2, 
 0.0000113751 -> 2, 0.0000258281 -> 1, 0.000181464 -> 3, 
 0.00031899 -> 8, 0.00236808 -> 10, 0.0207007 -> 10, 0.0518223 -> 4, 
 0.144338 -> 4, 0.57735 -> 3|>
*)
```

A numerically stable refactoring of `SinEta`:

```
SinEta[x_, y_] := With[{yy = y^2},
   With[{u = 4 yy + 3, w = 4 yy - 3, xx = x^2},
    With[{z = (u + Sqrt[u^2 + (8 w + 16  xx) xx])},
     Sqrt[(z - 4 xx)/(z + 4 xx)]
     ]]];

SinEta[x, y] - Sqrt[sinsquare[x, y]] // TrigToExp // 
 FullSimplify[#, {x, y} \[Element] Reals] &

(* 0 *)
```